# Unable to boot after repeated BSOD

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod

My computer will not boot into anything, other than Win10 safe mode on its boot drive. I cannot perform a clean install as every attempt to boot into a install USB causes a BSOD.

Find a description of my system followed by a brief explanation of the previous system configuration, and then an explanation of the testing and diagnosis I have done so far. I am now out of ideas and don’t know what to do next.

#### System Details

I have a i5 9600k, ASUS PRIME 390Z-P, 630w PSU and 32GB (4x8GB) of Corsair Vengeance memory.

I have a variety of drives types (HDD, SSD, NVME) and all different sizes. The main and target drive for OS installation is a Samsung 990 Pro 2TB.

#### Previous Configuration

I was running my boot drive as Windows 10 Pro on a Samsung 980 Pro 1TB. One day I came home from work and the CPU was pinned at 100%. I did some investigating which resulted in turned off hyper-v as the fix, however I continued to see my CPU pinned at 100% and then suddenly a couple of weeks later this behaviour subsided (it did not completely disappear, it became intermittent).

A few weeks later, I migrated my boot drive to the current 990 Pro and then started having boot issues. Originally, it would boot after a couple of tries. At this time I wasn’t using it often and I hadn’t noticed it had restarted and had stayed on a BSOD since. (It should be noted the BSOD error message is different every time)

#### Testing and diagnosis

Booting into safe mode from the 990 Pro works, both with networking and with command prompt. Sfc, bcd and other common command line tools report no errors with the OS, boot drive or other configuration.

Booting into the Win10 boot drive, Win10 USB installer, Win11 USB installer, WinPE USB all fail each time with a BSOD (random / new error code each time)

I have attempted to boot after the following: I have removed all drives from the system, the GPU, and all other peripherals. I have removed all but one memory stick and rotated which motherboard slot it is placed in.

I have tried every combination of secure boot, fast boot and CSM for each boot attempt too.

I have also completed a memory test (DOS style blue ish screen) with WinPE and the Win10 USB, which reports no errors with any of the 4 memory sticks (all tested individually)

To be thorough, I used numerous different USB drives to attempt to boot, to eliminate this as a factor, with no changes to boot success.

The BIOS has the latest update from ASUS, and has also been reset to factory defaults.

#### What to do?

To me the next logical step would be to attempt to eliminate the PSU, motherboard, CPU (in that order). However I do not have spares for these components that I can drop in, and I would like to avoid buying new components “just to see”.

I don’t believe I can conclude the CPU is dead, as it boots into safe mode just fine. I can even perform relatively heavy tasks like transcoding with ffmpeg without stability issues.

I would be truly grateful if anyone has some insight into any other troubleshooting tips or suggestions. My data is backed up so I am open to wiping / deleting / resetting anything (although not sure what this could apply to as it still BSODs with no drives!)

Comment: Any way to run manufacturer hardware diagnostics from a bootable USB Key ?

Comment: @John I’m not sure what you’re referring to by manufacturer hardware diagnostics. All bootable USBs I have attempted to create will not boot. Thanks!

Comment: If that is the case you may wish to get the machine serviced for hardware probblems.

Comment: Two more tests you might try: 1. Remove the internal SSD, replace with any good, blank, HHD or SSD, and try installing an OS from ISO - could be a "dirty" partition preventing boot. 2. Try booting from a Linux boot USB, e.g., Live Ubuntu.